# Averaging component of speed in speed distribution

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinetic-theory

> **Homework problem:** The molecules in a gas travel with different velocities. A particular molecule will have velocity $\vec v$ and speed $v =  |\vec v|$ and will move at angle $\theta$ to some chosen fixed axis. It has been given that the number of molecules in a gas with speeds between $v$ and $v + dv$ and moving at angles between $\theta$ and $\theta + d\theta$ to any chosen axis is given by $$\frac{1}{2} n f(v) \sin(\theta) d\theta,$$ where $n$ is the number of molecules per unit volume and $f(v)$ is some function of $v$ only, but NOT necessarily the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution. Show by integration that, $$\langle u^2\rangle= \frac{1}{3} \langle v^2\rangle$$, where $u$ is any Cartesian component of $v$, *e.g.* $v_x$, $v_y$, or $v_z$.

**My attempt at a solution:**

I know that we can write $\langle v\rangle$ as: $$\langle v\rangle = \frac{\int_0^{\infty} v f(v) dv}{\int_0^{\infty} f(v) dv}.$$ I also took $u$ to be the $z$-component of $v$, *i.e.*, $u = v \cos(\theta)$, since that makes $u$ only a function of $v$ and $\theta$. Then, as before, averaging over $v$ and $\theta$,

$$\langle u^2\rangle = \frac{\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\pi} u^2 f(v) dv d\theta}{\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\pi} f(v) dv d\theta}$$

which becomes, noting that $u^2 = v^2 \cos^2(\theta)$,

$$\frac{\int_0^{\pi} \cos^2(\theta) d\theta \int_0^{\infty} v^2 f(v) dv}{\pi \int_0^{\infty} f(v) dv}.$$

The $dv$-integrals in the numerator and the denominator give together the expression for $\langle v^2\rangle$. So, according to the question, the total angular part, in the numerator and the denominator, must give $\frac{1}{3}$, but it doesn't:

$$\frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \cos^2(\theta) d\theta \neq \frac{1}{3}.$$ I know that there isn't anything wrong in doing the integrals themselves (I have checked them using WolframAlpha) so there must be something wrong in the formulae I am using. What has gone wrong?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The probability distribution is not $f(v)$, but $\frac{1}{2} n f(v) \sin(\theta)$. Including this factor of $\sin\theta$ will give you the answer.